# Complex Bootstrap stacked columns on mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, stacked

i have this column from desktop

```
|      col-lg-5       | col-lg-2 | | col-lg-2 | | col-lg-2 |
```

how to make on mobile

```
|            col-sm-12           |
| col-sm-4 | col-sm-4 | col-sm-4 |
```

i try with this

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-5">
   xxx
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
   xxx
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
   xxx
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
   xxx
</div>
```

but on mobile displaying

```
|   col-12   |
|   col-12   |
|   col-12   |
|   col-12   |
```

Comment: which version of bootstrap you are using?

Comment: i used 4.0 version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to define the bootstrap grid system inside `.row` then and then you will have grids on the page.

Try this in your code,

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-5">
    xxx
  </div>
  <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2">
    xxx
  </div>
  <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2">
    xxx
  </div>
  <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2">
    xxx
  </div>
</div>
```

> **Note:** Bootstrap 4.0 version has removed `.col-xs` class. [Check available classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options).

And here is snippet also,

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-5">
    xxx
  </div>
  <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2">
    xxx
  </div>
  <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2">
    xxx
  </div>
  <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2">
    xxx
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `col-sm-4` or `col-xs-4`, you should use `col-4` which implies you want it to span 4 columns not just for viewport between sm and md or xs and md, but for all viewports upto md. Do it like this.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-5">
        xxx
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
       xxx
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
       xxx
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
       xxx
    </div>
</div>
```

You do not have to write `col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-5`, just writing `col-sm-12 col-lg-5` would be suffice. Similarly for other divs also.